# Using CouchDB as interface. Is it appropriate way?

Tags: interface, couchdb, mustache

our devices (microscopes with cameras) produce images and additional information to each image.
Now a middleware supplies wants to connect these devices to lab automation system. They have to acquire the data and we have to provide it. An astonishing thing for me was their interface suggestion - a very cryptical token separated format (ASTM E1394-97). Unfortunatelly, they even can't accomodate images in their protocol, and are aiming to get file-paths.

I thought it is not the up-to date approach. While lookink for alternatives, I saw CoachDB.
So, my idea was, our devices would import data including images in CoachDB and they could get the data. It seems even, that using mustache, we could produce the format they want (ascii-text) and placing URLs as image references instead of path's.

My question is, did someone applied CoachDB for such a use case already? It seems to be a little-bit misuse of CoachDB, as the main intention is interface not data storage. Another point disturbing me is, that the inventor of CoachDB went to other project Coachbase. Could it mean lack of support for CoachDB in the future?

Thank you very much for any insights and suggestions!

Comment: When CouchDB's inventor was hired by MemBase, CouchDB had already a very active and very dedicated community of developers and users. So don't worry: it's one of the best software community I have known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ok use-case and actually we're using CouchDB in such way - as proxing middleware between medical laboratory analyzers and LIS. Some of them publish images or pdf data on shared folders and we'd just loading them into related document as attachments.

More over you'd like to know, CouchDB is able to serve external processes (aka [`os_daemons`](http://davispj.com/2010/09/26/new-couchdb-externals-api.html)) and take care about their lifespan: restarting if someone had terminated and starting right after you update config options through HTTP interface. This helps to setup ASTM client and server processes since this protocol is different from HTTP (which is native for CouchDB) which communicates with devices and creates documents as regular CouchDB clients. In same way you may setup *daemons* to monitor shared folders for specific files. And all this is just CouchDB with few "low bounded" plugins.

Comment: +1: Great! Thank you for the info! Seems like you have quite similar infrastructure. I'll dig further in this direction. May I ask you, how long is your system in production since implementation? Another question, did you had experience with CoachDB before or did you hire a consultant for getting things running?

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz , overall CouchDB in production for us is 2 years, ASTM module - last half year. Feel free to mail me at {nickname}@gmail.com if you have questions about or ask on [users@couchdb](http://couchdb.apache.org/#mailing-list) mailing list - I'm sure there you may found others with same or related experience.